# Уязвимость в DNS COMODO

Tags: безопасность, dns

Я вот похоже нашёл, что SECURE COMODO DNS либо агрит гугол, либо был взломан. У нас в carolines.ru были установлены эти dnsки и 19.02 стали возникать проблемы с google.

Собственно, подменяет правильные адреса на иные.

```
nslookup docs.google.com 
╤хЁтхЁ: ns1.recursive.dns.com 
Address: 8.26.56.26 

Не заслуживающий доверия ответ: 
╚ь : docs.google.com 
Addresses: fe80:3::225:90ff:fe19:4b12 
174.129.145.134
```

Если в 2011 он подменял сервера mail.ru и yandex.ru (https://yandex.ru/blog/safesearch/254). 
то теперь он подменяет сервера google.com. Забавно, что на тот же самый ip адрес, что и в 2011 (174.129.145.134). Как я понял, туда перенаправляют с доменов, которые не нравятся комодо. В 2011 такое внезапное внесение яндекса и мейла было связано с тем, что этот самый 174.12.. распространял нехорошее.

Соответственно, я сменил DNS и всё заработало.

Черт его знает, что еще было подменено, наверное не только docs.google.com

Собственно - подскажите, что делать с этой информацией? С яндексом, судя по новостям, каша была серьёзная.
Хорошо бы comodo побыстрее исправили. Да и для гугла лучше бы выдавали предупреждения, что dnsки поменять надо. Им-то я написал.
Но и в новостях неплохо бы написать, может у людей ничего не работает, да и лучше снять - мало ли может опять там все протроянили. В принципе очередная история фейла комодо.
Потратил много времени и так не понял кому и КАК написать. чтобы выдать эту новость кому-нибудь?

Comment: Ответ очевиден же - надо перестать пользоваться "левыми" DNS-серверами.

Comment: Писать видимо в comodo. И не "взломали" его, а просто он на гугловских ip нашел что то вредное и решил заблочить. и действительно не ясно зачем вообще пользоваться такими кривыми сервисами. Он реально от чего то защищает ?

Comment: Comodo молчит. Гугол уже ответил, что заявка их заинтересовала будут разбираться типа. 
Да, может это супер косяк. А может и нет - в 2011 все было точно так же. 
Правда, у меня вопрос был скорее как кому написать.